# Pass Count of Group Rows fro one group to another

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I have one group that groups by month, and another group that groups by year beneath it. In the month group row there is a sum of a field. In the year group I want to display the monthly average, not the sum for the year.

```
Jan 2008    10
Feb 2008    15
Mar 2008    35
2008        20
```

So 2008 summary line is 60/3 = 20. I suspect it is something using CountRows but not sure how to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just do something like this...

```
=Sum(Fields!myAmountField.Value) / CountDistinct(Fields!myMonthField.Value)
```

if your report spans more than one year you may have to do something like

```
=Sum(Fields!myAmountField.Value, "myYearGroupName") / CountDistinct(Fields!myMonthField.Value, "myYearGroupName")
```

Comment: Worked great! Thanks!